# Click on td and display value of next td

Tags: jquery

I have this which works making a button displaying as its value whatever is on the first cell of the row.

```
$('.oui').click(function(){
    var valor = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
    $url = '{{URL::route('postpollspage')}}'; 
    $.post($url, { oui: valor });      
    $(this).attr('value', valor);
    $(this).css('background', 'green');
    $(this).css({ 'color': 'white', 'font-size': '150%' });
});
```

```html
<td class="oui"><input type ="button" value = "VOTE OUI" class="oui"></td>
```

But I need a slight modification of this:

1. Instead of leaving a button, I want to get rid of it and leave the cell upon which clicking it should do what the button did, that is, display the value of what the first cell of the row has. What happens if I remove the button is that indeed the cell turns green on clicking but does not display a value.
2. Second thing I want is that upon clicking on the cell, it should make the value of the cell next to it, (whether to its left or right), null. This is because those cells represent FOR and AGAINST in a polling. So if you click yes, you make no = zero and vice versa.

Any help would be revered with deep appreciation.

UPDATE:

I have been asked to post my HTML structure, here it is:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Tantiem</th>
                <th>Prenom</th>
                <th>Nom</th>
                <th>Oui</th>    
                <th>Non</th>
                <th>Abstention</th>    
                <th>Absent</th>                                      
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($polls as $vote)       
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $vote->tantieme }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $vote->prenom}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $vote->nom }}</td>          
            <td class="oui"><input type ="button" value = "VOTE OUI" class="oui"></td>              
            <td class="non"><input type ="button" value = "VOTE NON" class="non"></td>               

                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>      
    </table>
```

Comment: post your html structure.

Comment: removal of button won't affect the code as long as `td` has class `oui`. And for next `td` use `$(this).next()`. Its easy, you can do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I would also have thought it wouldn't affect, but as I indicated, when I removed the button, it did not display the value anymore, only the color. As you can see in the td definition, it does have class oui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the jsfiddel : http://jsfiddle.net/x3D9n/2/

For Pt. 1 changed :

```
 $(this).text(valor); //  $(this).attr('value',valor);
```

and 
For Pt. 2, Added

```
$(this).next().text('');
```

**Some docs :**

http://api.jquery.com/next/

http://api.jquery.com/prev/

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: thank you a lot for the help. but "next" means, left or right? or is there something like: previous and next?

Comment: @SovietPatriotCCCP Yes there are next() and prev() methods. See links above.

Comment: Thank you "thecbuilder" for your kind help. Thank you also for the information about the existence of "prev" and "next".